# Error handling in embedded systems development

Tags: c, embedded, firmware

I am developing a Firmware and I am using 3 layers: Driver, Platform and Application. In order to handle the communication between these layers, I am using an approach where each function will return a success/failure flag:

```
typedef enum {
  FW_ERROR = 0,
  FW_OK    = 1
}FWStatusTypeDef;
```

Every function in my FW looks like this:

```
FWStatusTypeDef function1(void)
{
  /* Do some stuff */
  ..
  ..

  if(something_wrong_happens)
    return FW_ERROR;
  return FW_OK;
}


FWStatusTypeDef function2(void)
{
  /* Do some stuff */
  ..
  ..
  if(something_wrong_happens)
    return FW_ERROR;

  return FW_OK;
}
```

The approach I am using is good for debugging but when running the application, I want to identify which function is sending an error flag. In other words, I want to keep track of errors and display them in a screen

Example:

```
FWStatusTypeDef OpenTheDoor(void)
{
  if (!KeyIsAvailable())
  {
    return FW_ERROR;
  }
  Door->Open();

  if (!DoorIsOpen())
  {
     return FW_ERROR;
  }

  return FW_OK;
}

FWStatusTypeDef KeyIsAvailable(void)
{
  return GetKeyStatus();
}

FWStatusTypeDef DoorIsOpen(void)
{
  return GetDoorStatus();
}
```

In this example, when I call `OpenTheDoor()` and it returns `FW_ERROR`. I won't be able to know if the problem is that the key is missing or there was another problem while trying to open the door (for example a cow is blocking it because it hates me).

I've been thinking and I came up with this solution: An Error code handler.

```
typedef enum {
  ERROR_1 = 0,
  ERROR_2 = 1,
  ERROR_k = k, // A cow is blocking the door
  ERROR_n = n  // The key is missing
}ErrorIdTypeDef;

static ErrorIdTypeDef ErrorCode;

// Getter
ErrorIdTypeDef GetErrorCode(void)
{
  return ErrorCode;
}

// Setter
void SetErrorCode(ErrorIdTypeDef code)
{
  ErrorCode = code;
}
```

Each function will use the error handler exposed Setter.

```
FWStatusTypeDef OpenTheDoor(void)
{
  if (!KeyIsAvailable())
  {
    SetErrorCode(ERROR_n);
    return FW_ERROR;
  }
  Door->Open();

  if (!DoorIsOpen())
  {
     SetErrorCode(ERROR_k);
     return FW_ERROR;
  }

  return FW_OK;
}

FWStatusTypeDef KeyIsAvailable(void)
{
  return GetKeyStatus();
}

FWStatusTypeDef DoorIsOpen(void)
{
  return GetDoorStatus();
}
```

In the application layer, I read the error code using the exposed getter API if an error occurs:

```
if (!OpenTheDoor())
{
  ErrorIdTypeDef theError;
  theError = GetErrorCode();
  switch(theError)
  {
    case ERROR_k:
      DisplayOnTheScreen("A cow is blocking the door.");
      break;

    case ERROR_n:
      DisplayOnTheScreen("You don't have a key.");
      break;

    ...
    ...

    default:
      break;
  }
}
else
{
  DisplayOnTheScreen("Door is open");
}
```

Now, my questions are not about the syntax, they're more about "good practices". Does this approach have any limitation ? Is there another known practice to get the same result ? In other words, Am I complicating things here ?

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for this question, yes asking about embedded firmware is on topic, but your question might be quite fitting on code review or some other more general programming SE- as it is nothing inherently embedded about it. Just point out some of the limitations (no exceptions etc.) and I'd guess you'd get better answers there.

Comment: I'd ask if you really need to have that much error handling at the TOP level. I think you should be handling it at the levels you care about. IE, in the platform layer, do something specific to a specific error in the driver layer (USB Buffer underflow, better do something). The platform reports up to the application layer that there was an issue in the driver, but the applications layer can't really do anything to fix it. Think about what layer can do what action.

Comment: @yhyrcanus The thing is: I need to display error messages on the screen. The user needs to know whats going on behind. Think about it like a smartphone. you can't just handle errors in the back and display "ERROR" to the user. You need to tell him where the problem comes from.

Comment: You could also build something using C's `__LINE__` macro. Or `__FUNC__` if C99.

Comment: if you need to display the error to the user then a few choices.  1) you print the error where it occurs and return pass/fail fails are echoed upstream without further printouts.  2) you use an enum type approach with unique error codes/numbers and 2a) just print the number they google the problem or 2b) you have code at a top level that turns the code into a string to print.  2a is good for embedded as it has the least cost from a resources perspective.

Comment: Any time you ask a best practices question or best anything question the answer is "primarily opinion based", as there is no such thing as a general best practice or best anything.   Too many factors, in rare occasions you can make a short list of pretty goods, but each will beat out one of the others "depending" on other factors.  And sometimes they will tie with no single one being "best".

Comment: and this is a stackoverflow question not an EE question, and at stackoverflow it should get closed as primariliy opinion based.

Comment: @Pryda what's an end user going to do about a USB underrun? Or an I2C clock timeout? When my smartphone can't connect to the internet, it doesn't tell me the specific error that the radio had. Just no signal, or whatever.

Comment: @yhyrcanus. Imagine that you have a sensor connected via SPI to your uC. The end user user can change the sensor (let's sat its a mountable sensor, when you mount it, you're connecting the SPI bus and the alimentation). Imagine that the user want to make a measurement using that sensor and he forgot to plug it or he plug it incorrectly (connection problem). The end user clicks on "Measure" and the sensor displays 0 although that the real value is 5. How could the user know that the sensor is not well connected ? What I aim to do is to check if I can read and write using SPI before the request

Comment: Of course a simple presence detection solution using a GPIO input would solve the problem in the example but that was just an example. What I am building here is a solution where the end user should be informed about lower layers errors

Comment: In that case you just need to say "device not found; check connections." You don't need to say the very specific "device on Chip select 5 didn't respond to a SPI transaction." I'm also not saying don't make the detailed error message unreachable for debugging purposes. Just consider how each layer will use it. That is, your application layer shouldn't care if it's SPI or I2C or whatever.

The answers here are great (ie use enums). The only thing I'd add is bitshifts/masks are your friend when you can run into multiple errors.

Answer (score 4):

Once the project complexity increases, I tend to develop embedded firmware like so:

1. First, as you did, I set up a typedef to contain the "return status" values of any exposed functions:

   ```
   typedef enum
   {
       FLASH_SUCCESS = 0,
       FLASH_IS_BUSY,
       FLASH_BAD_ADDRESS,
       FLASH_DATA_TOO_LARGE,
       (etc)
   } flashReturn_t
   ```
2. I have the calling routines handle any of these responses. Early in development, I simply call an error handling function which blinks an LED at me in an endless loop. The blinking pattern tells me which error happened. (My projects generally don't have convenient human-readable output devices...)
3. As development progresses, the different error cases become managed in more appropriate ways. Eventually, there is nothing left to call the error handler and so it can be removed.

I like this because:

1. It lets me work on larger program flow first, and fine tune the error handing later.
2. It provides a running list of error cases I need to work on, and
3. At any point, I could choose to call any remaining (unhandled) error cases "good enough", turn on a watchdog timer, and release the project.

In the unlikely event that an unexpected error happens, the WDT will timeout during the error handler loop and the system will reset. Which, of course, is what a WDT is supposed to do!

My error handler is set up like this:

```
typedef enum
{
    ERR_CC1101_TXFIFO_EMPTY = 1,
    ERR_CC1101_TXFIFO_FULL,
    ERR_CC1101_RXBYTES_TIMEOUT,
    ERR_CC1101_TXBYTES_TIMEOUT,
    ERR_FLASH_CORRUPTED,
    ERR_FLASH_CAL_BAD_DATA,
    ERR_STAT_EVENT_QUEUE_FULL,
    ERR_PB_INVALID_TYPE,
    ERR_IMU_INIT_FAIL,
    ERR_IMU_BAD_CONFIG
} errortype_t;

void ErrorHandler(errortype_t Error);
```

Notice that I've grouped errors by subsystem. Also, the first entry =1 (not 0) because those indexes are what causes my LED to flash. It doesn't help to flash zero times :)

Comment: "Notice that I've grouped errors by subsystem. Also, the first entry =1 (not 0) because those indexes are what causes my LED to flash. It doesn't help to flash zero times :)"  Well, you could have something like `ERR_NONE` for no errors at index 0. And flash zero times for zero errors.

Comment: @Lundin True! But my routine is a dead-end in code, basically just an infinite loop with some indications. So in my case, I'd never call that routine unless there was something very wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Using enums for error codes is common practice. The whole purpose of using enum over for example `bool` is to get more information.

The pattern you suggest with a common "last error" handler is not recommended though. This has been tried historically many times, never with good results. Must infamously the Windows API GetLastError() function.

The problem with "last error" handlers are several: they are not thread/interrupt safe and they only remember the last error. If you set `FW_ERROR_KEY` from a function, from the time that happens until you print the error, another error could have happened. You then print the wrong reason and get the wrong diagnostic.

The common way to handle errors is instead rather something like this:

```
for(;;)
{
  kick_watchdog();

  result = state_machine[state]();

  if(result != OK)
  {
    error_handler(result);
  }
}
```

That's what the main loop looks like in many bare metal MCU projects. All errors are passed down from drivers up to the application layer, and error handling is centralized.

The application layer might then make the call to ignore certain errors, or handle them, or replace their error codes with another code. Etc.

Comment: Is it considered a code duplication to separate the state machine and error codes ?

for example:

`CurrentState->Set(STATE_NOT_READY);  

    if (!(MyDriver->Init(&initStruct) != FW_OK))  
    {  
        ErrorHandler->Set(ERROR_CODE_INIT_FAILED);  
        return FW_ERROR;  
    }  

    CurrentState->Set(STATE_READY);`

Comment: @Pryda Not really. It is good design to centralize the code picking the next state to one single place in the program, to avoid "stateghetti". This can very well be merged with the error handler, so that one central piece of code makes a call on which state to execute next, based on results of the previous one. For example this is how safety-critical systems work: revert to a safe state in case of errors.

Comment: So. Let me get this straight. You decry Try/Catch blocks but you have basically coded a Try/Catch block, by hand, as your example of good error handling? Some people see the high-level patterns, other people just get caught up in the details...

Comment: @EdgarBrown Do you know the difference between return from sub-routine and non-conditional branches? If so, you'll know that this is not exception handling, as there is no spaghetti code of any kind present. The C equivalent to C++ exception handling are the horrible setjmp/longjmp.

Comment: Not being able to understand or properly use the mechanisms provided by a programming language or operating system is no excuse. setjmp/longjmp is a far cry from the considerably cleaner and better structured Try/Catch blocks. Likewise, anyone that deals with general exceptions, reentrancy, interrupts, multiple threads, parallelism, semaphores, and mutexes should have absolutely no problem properly dealing with the comparatively trivial concepts behind a Try/Catch. No need for spaghettification. But, in its simplest from, a Try/Catch just does exactly what you wrote in your code.

Comment: @EdgarBrown Just read the link I posted. And have fun debugging unhandled exceptions. Never did that before, right...

Comment: @Lundin I had already read the link you posted. It’s just someone’s opinion, not very different from shouting that Rock and Roll corrupts children’s minds. So I’ll just repeat myself, any tool is fine if you know what you are doing. Some tools make it harder for you to know what you are doing. But the Try/Catch concept is very easy to grasp and use appropriately. Some languages, like Swift, make it nearly impossible to have unhandled exceptions unless you purposefully make the effort to program them in. Other languages are very lax on what they let you throw at an unsuspecting handler.

Comment: @EdgarBrown The question then is: what makes you think you know what you are doing? Have you ever examined the flash size of a program with or without exceptions? Exceptions means RTTI and RTTI means bloat. It's a fact, not opinions. Single step your program instruction by instruction and see what a mess it made.

Comment: @Lundin engineering is about compromises. I once had to code a simple integer multiply in assembly because I could not afford the stack bloat that C was generating. On the other extreme I had to write 5000 lines of Try/Catch code to handle 20 lines of real code because of a crappy commercial operating system that shall remain unnamed. Without it, the task would have been impossible. If you can’t afford the bloat you code in assembly, and as I already said: C is just a glorified assembler.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get a definitive answer to this, just many opinions.

Error handling is one of the most problematic aspects of software development, it’s commonly deemed unnecessary by the inexperienced and nearly always the cause of nasty problems.

That’s why modern languages have striven to incorporate error handling at the most basic levels of their syntax.

Try/catch structures are now quite common. And languages like Swift have reduced what used to be a page of bounds checking into a single line.

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with your approach, the problem that you might not have considered is the increasing exponential complexity of the steps required to revert actions when errors occur. This is not a big issue when you are only one or two steps deep into a process, but it can quickly become overwhelming.

Try/Catch blocks, at the very least allow you to separate your straightforward application code from the messy tree that is handling errors when things don’t go as planned.

In your error handler, you don’t seem to have considered that a single error could trigger multiple errors in its wake.

Comment: By Try/Catch you mean goto ? Because As far as I know, C doesn't support Try/Catch.

Comment: @Pryda and that’s one of the reasons why C is not a modern language. It’s a glorified assembler at best. I wouldn’t consider anything less than C++ unless the processing resources are so constrained that assembly becomes desirable.

Comment: "A glorified assembler at best." - Come now. No reason to troll the stack exchange!

Comment: @bitsmack it’s not trolling. It’s a fact that anyone proficient in assembly code can see. You can have more powerful constructs in assembly macros than in C!!! C was conceived in the 70’s as a universal portable assembler, it has evolved somewhat but not enough to leave behind its roots. That’s why C code tends to be very closely tied to the architecture it runs in, even standard data types are an afterthought!!!! Its main advantage is to be able to reuse some of the higher-level code without rewriting. But you can say the same thing about Pascal’s P-code.

Comment: To each his own! I'm not interested in arguing. But I am quite proficient in both C and a few different assembly languages, and I see things differently. Have a nice day! (really!) :)

Comment: @bitsmack I have been programming since before personal computers (I even used punch cards in high-school), and i am proficient in more languages than I can count.  So my sequence went something like this: HP-25 -> TI-59 -> Basic -> Fortran -> Assembler -> Pascal -> Forth -> Lisp -> Object Pascal -> Matlab -> Mathematica -> YACC -> Perl -> C -> C++ -> C#. I really learned how to program when I learned Pascal (completely changing my coding style). By the time I was introduced to C I already knew what a high-level language was supposed to look like, and also how to write a compiler for them.

Comment: Exception handling is one of the most heavily criticised parts of C++, very much unsuitable for embedded systems. try/catch is by no means "modern", but a language flaw inherited from the 1980s. See for example http://www.lighterra.com/papers/exceptionsharmful/. And this is why we don't consider C++ for embedded systems: there's always some PC programmer aimlessly abusing the numerous bad but available features. In addition, those who can't separate program design from programming language should leave program design to someone else.

Comment: @Lundin Any programmer that does not know how to deal with exceptions, in general, and with keeping atomicity in the face of variant program flow has no place doing embedded programming. Blaming the tool for someone’s incompetence is just ignorant. As someone said, with C is too easy to shoot yourself in the foot, C++ loads the gun and aims it for you. My first experience with error exception handling was in assembler in an embedded system, I had to write safe atomic reentrant code to handle errors being thrown directly by the bare-metal processor. Unwinding a state is intrinsically hard.

Comment: If someone tries to remove a component from a PCB and does so with a chainsaw, you should surely blame the person. But the real question is why there is a chainsaw available in the electronics lab in the first place. It is powerful for sure, but it is big, bulky, dangerous, smelly and takes lots of time to start up. The quote you are looking for is "C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off" - Bjarne Stroustrup, the creator of C++.

Comment: @Lundin as someone that has removed components from a PCB with a blowtorch and soldered with a kitchen stove, any tool is fine if you actually know what you are doing and you have the skills to do it properly. A bare-metal processor already throws exceptions, there is no way around that, it is an intrinsic property of the real world. All programming languages have to deal with that and encapsulate it in a way that oblivious programmers can understand. Try/catch is just a tool that can bring some sanity to exception handling. Mere error return codes are incomplete, cumbersome, and messy.

Comment: My point is that we should teach beginners to use a soldering iron rather than to master the blowtorch. And your reasoning is based on the assumption that the people who designed the blowtorch actually had a clue about de-soldering of electronics and designed it with that in mind, which is highly unlikely. And if one particular blowtorch model has been fuelled by hallucinogenic gas since 2011, I would stay clear of it for any purpose. As for exception handling in C++, it has absolutely nothing to do with MCU hardware exceptions, apart from the similar sounding-names.

Comment: @Lundin nothing to do? Really? Besides having to walk the stack in the same way for the same basic reasons? Besides being the exact same exception handling model being brought up to a higher level, I guess. Not being able to abstract the problem away from the implementation details is a sign of someone that should never attempt object-oriented programming.

Comment: Yes really. How would you solve an unimplemented op code exception or clock failure exception using C++ `try/catch`?

Comment: @Lundin that would not be advisable as it is clearly in a different “ring” of exception handling, and betrays the way of thinking of someone that can’t see the difference. But if you really have to: you simply walk back the stack the same way you have to do with any other processor exception, encapsulate the exception in a way that is understandable by C++ primitives, make the processor state “safe”, and exit through the current catch handler routine. Probably no more than a page of code, some assembly might be involved.

Comment: Walk back the stack? The MCU just told you that the clock is dead, or that your program counter is in outer space. No amount of C++ will save you. And that's the difference between hw exceptions and C++ ones.

Comment: @Lundin how exactly did the cpu “tell you” that if it has no clock? How is it that exception code is being executed then? And, how exactly did the exception get called if there was no stack? I did say it wasn’t advisable as it is in a different category of errors altogether, didn’t I? ANY operating system has to be able to handle this. ANY respectable operating system deals with this as gracefully as it can. It is the ultimate “catch” block around your code. In an embedded system you are writing the operating system. Being written in C++, C, or Befunge has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You may do one thing to make things simpler.

Take one global char buffer with sufficient size.(call it as error message string)

Fill it with error message if something goes wrong.

And then display error message.

For example:

```
FWStatusTypeDef OpenTheDoor(void)

{

  if (!KeyIsAvailable())

  {

    Fill the error message string with "You don't have a key."

    return FW_ERROR;

  }



//Remaining code 



  return FW_OK;

}


if (!OpenTheDoor())

{

Print error message string.

}
```